# Overload based on existence of dependent type

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, sfinae, overload-resolution

I have two templated functions with the same name (`foo`). Their signatures differ only in the type of the second parameter, which is dependent on the template parameter `T`. What has surprised me is that I can use this to overload depending on whether `T::A` or `T::B` is an existent type. Is this something which is specially provided for in the standard (if so, a reference would be much appreciated), or am I just being dense in not recognising this as basic overload resolution?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void foo(T t, typename T::A* a = 0) {
  cout << "Had an A" << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void foo(T t, typename T::B* b = 0) {
  cout << "Had a B" << endl;
}

struct HasAnAType {
  typedef int A;
};

struct HasABType {
  typedef int B;
};

struct HasAAndBTypes {
  typedef int A;
  typedef int B;
};

int main() {
  HasAnAType a;
  HasABType b;
  HasAAndBTypes ab;

  foo(a);  // prints "Had an A"
  foo(b);  // prints "Had a B"
  foo(ab); // won't compile: 'ambiguous call to overloaded function'
}
```

For background, I discovered this was possible when looking into the implementation of `std::enable_shared_from_this`, which relies on this type of overloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the spec defines overload resolution:

> Overload resolution is a mechanism for selecting the best function to
>   call given a list of expressions that are to be the arguments of the
>   call and a set of candidate functions that can be called based on the
>   context of the call.
>
> the selection of the best function is the same in all cases: First, a
>   subset of the candidate functions (those that have the proper number
>   of arguments and meet certain other conditions) is selected to form a
>   set of viable functions. Then the best viable function is selected
>   based on the implicit conversion sequences needed to match each
>   argument to the corresponding parameter of each viable function.

For template functions, there is additional rule:

> For each function template, if the argument deduction and checking
>   succeeds, the template arguments (deduced and/or explicit) are used to
>   synthesize the declaration of a single function template
>   specialization which is added to the candidate functions set to be
>   used in overload resolution. If, for a given function template,
>   argument deduction fails, no such function is added to the set of
>   candidate functions for that template.

These rules lead to what is called as SFINAE, in case of overload resolution for template functions .

Comment: Thanks for all three answers - SFINAE was indeed the gap in my knowledge. I chose @basav's answer for also highlighting the part of the spec that provides for SFINAE.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), the overload `void foo(T t, typename T::B* b = 0)` is *removed* when `T::B` doesn't exist (similar for `T::A`)

So when both are available, both overloads are viable, and so the call is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this is not 'regular' overloading. It is called SFINAE. More information is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error